# An inequality related to supermartingale?

Tags: probability, martingales

> Let $X_n\ge0,n\ge0$, be a supermartingale. Show that $CP(\sup X_n>C)\le EX_0$.

I tried to use the inequality supermartingale satisfies, which is $E(X_n|\cal {F_{n-1}})$$\le X_{n-1}$. However, I have no clue to proceed.

Could someone kindly give some hint? Thanks!

Comment: Hints: Stopping times. Markov inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Let $T= \inf\{n \geq 0; X_n >C\}$, where $C>0$. Then $T$ is a stopping time. By the optional stopping theorem, $E(X_{T\wedge k}) \leq E(X_0)$, for all $k>0$. However, note that, for $k>0$,
\begin{align*}
E(X_{T\wedge k}) &\geq E\left(X_{T\wedge k} \mathbb{I}_{\{\sup_{n\leq k} X_n >C\}} \right)\\
&\geq CP(\sup_{n\leq k} X_n >C).
\end{align*}
That is, for $k>0$, 
\begin{align*}
CP(\sup_{n\leq k} X_n >C) \leq E(X_0).
\end{align*}
The final result follows immediately.